# Selecting Persons Name beginning on the right

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I know how to do a left, right and substring in T-SQL, but I'm having difficulty extracting just the name of the person below since the length of the name are not the same. Any ideas or syntax that I can use to extract just the name? Thanks

Data Value:

```
581;#Jackson, Daniel H; 501;#Sims, Katy L; 606;#Lawrence, Jennifer O
```

Comment: What is your expected output for data values `581;#Jackson, Daniel H; 501;#Sims, Katy L; 606;#Lawrence, Jennifer O`?

Comment: Actually it is a SELECT <FIELD> FROM <TABLE>. I wanted to know if there is other SQL syntax beside LEFT, SUBSTRING or RIGHT. Result should be just the Last Name, First Name and Initial.

Comment: So in the given example, there're 3 rows obtained from your query `SELECT <FIELD> FROM <TABLE>`, which are `581;#Jackson, Daniel H;`, `501;#Sims, Katy L;` and `606;#Lawrence, Jennifer O`? It's not clear what field that you're using. I suggest you to edit your post by adding your original query and reformat the output _Data Value_.

Comment: Mincong it is a simple select statement Select Createdby from Table1. The expected result should be Last Name, First Name and Middle Initial only.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of the name dynamically using PATINDEX, but it assumes that the Names are ALWAYS formatted the same way.

Here is an example of a TSQL Select that will give select the first names from the data you supplied:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    FullName VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT #Temp VALUES (581, 'Jackson, Daniel H')
INSERT #Temp VALUES (606, 'Lawrence, Jennifer O')

SELECT ID, FullName , SUBSTRING(FullName, PATINDEX('%, % _', FullName) + 2, 
    PATINDEX('% _', FullName) - PATINDEX('%, %', FullName) - 2) FirstName
FROM #Temp
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a function to split up CSV-Strings:

```
create function Do_Split 
  (@InputString  NVARCHAR(4000)
  ,@Delimiter    NVARCHAR(50) = ';')
RETURNS @Items TABLE (Item NVARCHAR(4000)) AS

BEGIN --Function
IF (@Delimiter = ' ')
BEGIN
  SET @Delimiter = ';'
  SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
END;

IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '') SET @Delimiter = ';';

DECLARE @Item          NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ItemList      NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @DelimIndex    INT

SET @ItemList = @InputString;
SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0);
WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
  BEGIN
  SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex);
  INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item);

-- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
  SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex);
  SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0);
  END;  -- End WHILE

IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
  BEGIN
  SET @Item = @ItemList;
  INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item);
  END;
ELSE      -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString);
  END;

RETURN
END -- End Function
go
```

Usage:

```
 SELECT * FROM Do_Split('581;#Jackson, Daniel H; 501;#Sims, Katy L; 606;#Lawrence, Jennifer O',';');
```

Result:

```
581
#Jackson, Daniel H
 501
#Sims, Katy L
 606
#Lawrence, Jennifer O
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear how your data looks like, because your example concatenates multiple values in one row.

**Case 1**

Assume that there're 2 columns `id` and `full_name` in `your_table`. The semicolon `;` was added by you intentionally to distinguish columns. In this case, you can obtain the value of full name using the function `RIGHT`. The length would be the length of `full_name` minus 1 which excludes the `#`.

```
--
-- id  full_name
-- --  ---------
-- 581 #Jackson, Daniel H
-- 501 #Sims, Katy L
-- 606 #Lawrence, Jennifer O
--
SELECT RIGHT(full_name, LEN(full_name) - 1) AS full_name
FROM your_table;
```

**Case 2**

If the above solution is not suitable, let's discuss another case. Assume that there's 1 column `content` in `your_table` and 3 rows. The semicolon `;` was inside the value of `content` and need to be treated explicitly. In this case, you can obtain the value of full name using the function `SUBSTRING`. The full name will begin after just after the index of char `#` and this index can be obtained using [CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx):

```
--
-- content
-- -------
-- 581;#Jackson, Daniel H
-- 501;#Sims, Katy L
-- 606;#Lawrence, Jennifer O
--
SELECT SUBSTRING(content, CHARINDEX('#', content) + 1, 1000) AS full_name
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: The above solution works! Thank you so much Mincong.. simple code.. :)

Comment: Great news @Arsee !! It's my pleasure to be able to help you. Could you accept my answer?

Comment: How do I accept your answer? Sorry I'm getting familiar with the site structure.

Comment: No pb @Arsee, you can check here : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work